# UIGestureRecognizer Pass-Though View

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios8, uigesturerecognizer

How do I create a view that allows some gestures to "pass-through", basically I have 2 views the top view completely covers the other, I need the top view to handle left/right swipes and the one below has a UIScrollView that needs to respond to up/down swipes, tap and long press, so essentially pass the events down the chain.

Is this the wrong approach?

Comment: There was a presentation at wwdc 2014 that might be relevant: "Advanced Scrollviews and Touch Handling TechniquesFrameworksiOS". Hope it gives you some insight

Comment: A very informative [video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/?include=236#236) thanks! though their demo explains how to interact with views that are not completely overlapping,  but there is a lot of good gesture info in that talk.